# LocationListener.onLocationChanged on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, location

I have a application use the coarse (network based) location, first request the last know location if null attach a LocationListener but how i can test this in the emulator, i have two devices and work fine but i want to test in other android versions

**Note**: I have tried sending positions from DDMS but does not work